# How to check a JPanel contains JLabel or not?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I have 16 JLabel in a Map, and a JPanel. Now I want to check in that JPanel contains a JLabel or not among 16.
I have tried this approach:

```
private int PanelContains(JPanel panel) {
    JLabel Value;
    for (Entry<Integer, JLabel> entry : Blackbox.entrySet()) {
        Value = entry.getValue();
        if (panel.getName() == Value.getParent().getName()) {
             return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am comparing with their name. But I am getting `"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"` error on `if (panel.getName() == Value.getParent().getName())` this line.

Comment: *"How to check a JPanel contains JLabel or not?"* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 3) See [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/418556) ..

Comment: .. 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JLabel` without a parent can cause this exception. Please try the code below.

```
private int panelContains(JPanel panel) {
    JLabel Value;
    for (Entry<Integer, JLabel> entry : Blackbox.entrySet()) {
        Value = entry.getValue();
        if (Value.getParent() == panel) {
             return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I meant a panel mean specific panel.All 16 Labels are situated in Panel also, Here I want to check for specific Panel.
But in your code, it checks that, a JLabel situated on Panel or not, am I right ? But I don't want it.

Comment: It is checking if `Value` label is situated in the `panel` or not.

Comment: I think it will work as you want. Additionally, I realized that you are comparing strings with `==` which is wrong. Even if your way is correct you must compare strings with equals like that:  `panel.getName().equals(Value.getParent().getName())`.

Answer (score 2):

SwingUtilities contains a number of methods that could help you do this, but my guess is that [getAncestorNamed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorNamed(java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Component)) might be the most useful: